# Query to join 3 different tables in mysql and SUM

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables as given in the below example

1. ClassMaster

   - ClassMasterId (Primary Key)
   - ClassId
2. ClassDetails

   - ClassMasterId (Mapping with ClassMaster.ClassMasterId)
   - ClassSize
3. Range

   - ClassId (Mapping with ClassMaster.ClassId)
   - RangeStart, RangeEnd, Fees

ClassDetails table will have more than one record for a ClassMasterId like more than one section for a class. Fees in Range Table is set by range start and range end. This range is for the class size. Need a query to get total fees amount for each classsize for specific schoolid.

Is it possible to get it in a single query in MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    cm.ClassMasterId, r.RangeStart, r.RangeEnd, r.ClassSize, SUM(r.Fees) AS 'Fees'  
FROM
    ClassMaster cm
        INNER JOIN ClassDetails cd ON cd.ClassMasterId = cm.ClassMasterId
        INNER JOIN Range r ON r.ClassId = cm.ClassId
GROUP BY 
    cm.ClassMasterId, r.RangeStart, r.RangeEnd, r.ClassSize
```

Because this is MySql and your keys have the same name, if you prefer you could use the `using` syntax for the joins:

```
SELECT 
    cm.ClassMasterId, r.RangeStart, r.RangeEnd, r.ClassSize, SUM(r.Fees) AS 'Fees'  
FROM
    ClassMaster cm
        INNER JOIN ClassDetails cd USING (ClassMasterId)
        INNER JOIN Range r USING (ClassId)
GROUP BY 
    cm.ClassMasterId, r.RangeStart, r.RangeEnd, r.ClassSize
```